# WPF: Once I set a property in code, it ignores XAML binding forever more... how do I prevent that?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a button that has a datatrigger that is used to disable the button if a certain property is not set to true:

```
<Button Name="ExtendButton" Click="ExtendButton_Click"  Margin="0,0,0,8">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

That's some *very* simple binding, and it works perfectly. I can set "IsConnected" true and false and true and false and true and false, and I love to see my button just auto-magically become disabled, then enabled, etc. etc.

However, in my Button_Click event... I want to:

1. Disable the button (by using ExtendButton.IsEnabled = false;)
2. Run some asynchronous code (that hits a server... takes about 1 second).
3. Re-enable the button (by using ExtendButton.IsEnabled = true;)

The problem is, the very instant that I **manually** set IsEnabled to **either true or false**... my XAML binding will *never* fire again. This makes me very sad :(

I *wish* that IsEnabled was tri-state... and that true meant true, false meant false and null meant inherit. But that is not the case, so what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benny's answer provides one approach (and an excellent one).  Another is to extend your model to support the "in async operation" state and to add another trigger to respond to that:

XAML:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
  </DataTrigger>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInAsyncOperation}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void ExtendButton_Click(...)
{
  IsInAsyncOperation = true;
  // begin async operation
}

private void OnAsyncOperationComplete(...)
{
  // retrieve results etc.
  IsInAsyncOperation = false;
}
```

Note: You'd define the IsInAsyncOperation property on the same class as IsConnected; if that's a view model rather than the Window class, then you'll need to tweak the code-behind accordingly.

Comment: This is the solution that I was thinking of doing (seeing as I already have the one property that I made for the purpose of shaping a ton of controls in my XAML)... I'll add the other, and use it as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's a **much** better way to get this functionality in WPF. It's the [commanding system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx), and it's awesome. Any button, menu item, hot key, etc can be linked to a *single* command which automatically handles enabling/disabling (as you desire in your program). It's also clean and reusable, and sooooo easy to use.

For example, in an application of mine, I have an "about dialog" that shows up when the user hits F1. I created a command called `AboutCommand` by implementing `ICommand`.

```
public class AboutCommand:System.Windows.Input.ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true; // in this case the command is never disabled
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        // not needed in this case, but in commands when CanExecute actually
        // changes, this performs the "magic" of disabling/enabling your controls
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        new AboutWindow().ShowDialog(); //happens when the command is executed
    }
}
```

Then, in my window's xaml, I added*:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AboutCommand x:Key="About"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{StaticResource About}" Gesture="F1"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

You could *also* set the command to a button like so.

```
<Button Command="{StaticResource About}" Content="About this program"/>
```

Both the F1 key *and* the button would be disabled if `AboutCommand.CanExecute()` returned false.

*(I actually did it differently, because I'm using the MVVM pattern, but this works if you aren't using that pattern.)

Comment: I haven't gotten into the command system stuff yet... I'll definitely give it another look as you suggest.

Comment: It's really really awesome. =)

Comment: I think for my current code issue, I'm just going to add another property... but I'll be looking into / probably using commands as I move forward. Thanks a bunch!